# How do I pass the object downloaded asynchronously using webclient?

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, download, webclient

I am trying to download the data asynchronously of type Json.
(I know how to pass the uri, but not how/where to download it.)

Edit, I am on .NET 3.5

How do I do it in the following scenario:

```
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())

var downloaded;

{
    client.DownloadDataAsync(myUri, downloaded);
}

Console.WriteLine(downloaded);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `HttpClient` (found in the System.Net.Http namespace)?

Comment: because I need to run it asynchronously, otherwise my program crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET Framework 3.5 this sample code should get you going

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Uri myUri = new Uri("http://google.com");

    using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += Client_DownloadStringCompleted; 

        // the WebClient is NOT thread safe so you cannot make concurrent calls
        client.DownloadStringAsync(myUri);

        // if you need to wait for the operation to finish
        //while (client.IsBusy)
        //{
        //    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        //}
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void Client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Path.GetTempFileName(), e.Result);
}
```

However if you can use a newer version of .NET or .NET Core I would recommend using `HttpClient`

```
using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(myUri);
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // to download as a byte array and save locally:
    //      var bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    //      System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("YourPath", bytes);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately my framework does not accept await, this will not work.

Comment: What version of .NET Framework (or .NET Core) are you using?

Comment: I am using .NET 3.5

Comment: @ali.vic That's the kind of requirement you need to specify in your question.

Comment: @ali.vic I've added an example using .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: THanks Kane! this was more involved than I wanted, it but it works! Now, do you know how to make the result string into an object? If not, i'l ask a new question

Comment: @ali.vic you can use the `DownloadDataAsync` method on the WebClient. Don't forget to wire up the `DownloadDataCompleted` event. The event args will return a byte array.